# Title Case in AutoHotkey

Tags: case, title, autohotkey

Is it possible to transform the text in the Clipboard in a Title Case form?
For example if the text in the clipboard is "The quick brown fox" then the script will have to transform it into:

```
"The Quick Brown Fox"
```

It would be nice to also work with non-ASCII characters too (diacritics), transforming "anders ångström" into "Anders Ångström"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
StringUpper, ClipBoard , ClipBoard  , T
Send, ^v
Return
```

Comment: The solution is not title case but capitalizes each word. "In title case, articles, conjunctions, and prepositions are written with a lowercase letter unless they start the title" [Source](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/capital_letters_title_case.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Old question but in case anyone else in my boat looking for this or something similar [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/nnpwer/comment/h03h1ff/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) got me what I needed:

```
^!u::
clipboard := ""
send ^{c}
clipWait, 0.3
stringUpper, clipboard, clipboard
send ^{v}
return

^!l::
clipboard := ""
send ^{c}
clipWait, 0.3
stringLower, clipboard, clipboard
send ^{v}
return

^!t::
clipboard := ""
send ^{c}
clipWait, 0.3
stringLower, clipboard, clipboard, T
send ^{v}
return
```

**After setting up holding CTRL+ALT and "l", "u" or "t" will change the case of your selected text.**